# How do you earn the Enthusiast badge?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

I thought I would have this badge by now, but perhaps I didn't visit the site one day. Or perhaps I don't understand the meaning of "visit". The description for this badge says "Visited the site each day for 30 days." How do you trigger a "visit"? Do you have to ask or answer a question? Vote? Leave a comment?

Comment: If you have it set to reload everyday, that might be enough to get it trigger a "visit".

Comment: @BradGilbert Yes, that isn't enough to trigger a visit. You'll have to *do* something for it to trigger as a visit.

Comment: @Seth Actually I'm pretty sure that **is** how I got my [Fanatic](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic) badge on Stack Overflow. It probably doesn't work the same way it did back in 2009 though.

Answer (score 15):

I can't find it now, but there's another question similar to this with an answer along the lines of "you must perform an undisclosed amount of activity" each day to get credit for a visit that day. The reasoning is that they don't want to award the badge to someone just for pointing a bot at SO -- the idea is that you, presumably a human, have visited and at least clicked around to a couple of questions and maybe voted every day.

See the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485).

And: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) (my emphasis below)

> Enthusiast
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Fanatic (gold)
> - Visit the site for 30 days in a row
>
>   - This can be tracked in the user profile under "consecutive days"
>   - **Simply loading the site is not enough to count as a "visit"**
>
>     - **The exact amount of activity required to count as a visit is not public information**
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are not counted in local time
> - Sometimes called "the woot! badge" because it was sponsored by woot.com early in SO's history. The badge name was displayed using their logo during that time.
> - Source: [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485); FILL IN OTHERS?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you've clicked around every day? HTTP being a stateless protocol SO has no way to tell if you are "there" or not.

Comment: No, I can't be sure I didn't skip a day.  And yes, I know you have to do something to trigger a visit, I was just curious if anybody knew exactly what the rules were.  Is it simply requesting anything from the server?  Just hitting F5 on an open SO page is all it takes to register a visit?

Comment: Not sure really. I think all you have to do is surf around. I know I didn't comment/answer a question every day (I don't think) and I got mine.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is visit at least once a day, every day for 30 consecutive days. To make sure you get the badge, ensure that you're logged in to Stack Overflow (or Server Fault, as your case may be). It's also worth noting that a new day begins at 0:00 UTC, which is 20:00 (or 8:00 PM) EDT.

Comment: See, that's why I asked.  I have this site open in a browser, on a machine that runs around the clock.  So, I'm logged in around the clock.  There must be more to it than that.  Are you saying I have to explicitly log out and then back in to register a visit?

Comment: No. I don't know what to tell you - there were many days this past month that I didn't do more than click around for a bit, and I still got the badge. Is it possible you missed a day somewhere?

Comment: @raven: You say your machine "runs around the clock", but do you explicitly *do something* on the site every day? You can't just have the browser open to this site for 30 consecutive days, you have to at least click a link or something.

Comment: @raven - Only if you use a feature like Tab Mix Plus's auto reload to refresh the page every hour or so to keep your session alive.

Comment: This badge is such BS. I have visited the site for 50 days in a row, trying to get the Fanatic badge, always remembering to do it before 0:00 UTC happens, which is 6:00 PM in Texas. I'm on a trip in California right now, and I came onto StackExchange at 4:07 PM PST... forgetting about the timezones, and now my progress is entirely reset! NOOOO! Are you kidding me?! I was not even 10 minutes off!

Answer (score 2):

As Kyle said, its a matter of visiting at least once a day for 30 consecutive days. I'm not sure if it's just a matter of having a page open while logged in during that time but I can reveal how I achieved the badge.

I browse stackoverflow at work and at home and usually have it open in a tab all day long at work and 24/7 at home....my morning routine at home usually involves checking the latest questions so I typically refresh the page each day...and if I'm not at home, I usually check SO on my iPhone.

Between work, home, and my phone...its fairly easy to obtain the badge with minimal effort.

Answer (score -2):

There has to be a better way than UTC. Not only is it a strange way to count "consecutive days", but its worse than that. Like @kyle Cronin says Eastern time zone is 8:00 pm but that is only during daylight saving's time. It [changes](http://www.maar.us/utc_time_converter.html) to 7:00 pm during Eastern standard time. Just a strange way to do it with all them smart computer people around???

Comment: It's not really a strange way to do it. As long as you visit the site consistently every 24 hours, you will be fine. If you pick a time that isn’t affected by DST for you, great. If this is somehow impossible for 30 days, do not get the badge.

Comment: Actually the reason I became interested in this question is because I did earn the 30 day badge and was working on the gold badge for 100 days. unfortunately, visiting at 8:30 pm Central time on my 67th consecutive visit was not good enough. I had to visit by 7:00 pm because you know everyone knows new days start at 7:00 pm? Just saying this new day time arrangement is strange and penalizes honest effort for no good reason.

Comment: Sure, you had to visit by 7:00 PM, but you had 24 hours to do it. If you can’t… it’s just a badge and is not really penalizing you.

Comment: "Just a strange way to do it with all them smart computer people around???" this certainly does not contribute, there are more constructive ways, perhaps reasoning on how other site does it or sharing some information that can backup the need for having a clock change which might enhance the overall usage.