# Is there a minimum level of activity required to get the "Enthusiast" badge?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

I just got my Enthusiast badge on SuperUser (Woot! indeed), but haven't received it on ServerFault, despite me thinking I've been visiting both sites every day since I came back off holiday in mid August.

I've got both Google Chrome at home and Firefox at work to open all four sites at startup - so a) I don't have to open them manually and b) I don't miss a day. I know there was an issue with [Safari's top sites feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/did-safaris-top-sites-feature-earn-my-enthusiast-badge) so I was wondering if part of the fix was to require a certain amount of activity - not just opening the home page once.

If that's the case then fair enough, I know that I'm never going to be able to get much rep on SF anyway so missing the Enthusiast badge is not a big thing, but it will affect how I use SO and SU & whether it's worth me even trying for the Fanatic badge.

Of course I could have just missed a day without realising it and the badge will turn up at some point.

**UPDATE (20/09/2009)**

It's now been 4 days since I gained the Enthusiast badge on SU and it still hasn't turned up on SF. I don't think it was more than 4 days after I got back off holiday before I started visiting SF every day so (unless I did miss a day) I think the badge should have turned up by now. If it hasn't appeared in the next couple of days I'll fire off an e-mail asking if they can check the logs.

**UPDATE 2 (22/09/2009)**

An e-mail has been sent to the team. I'll post their reply as an answer.

Comment: Did you go camping? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13049/let-people-still-earn-the-woot-badge-if-they-register-for-a-holiday

Comment: @random - yes, at it happens ;)

Comment: I asked essentially the same question here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/how-do-you-earn-the-enuthusiast-badge  I gained this badge on SF by simply refreshing the page at least once a day.

Comment: @raven - thanks for the link, once again SO's search fails, I'll keep my current routine of having all four sites on my "home" tabs and as I open a fresh browser at work and home it'll eventually happen. It probably that I only started checking SF daily a few days after getting back off holiday, so I'll monitor for a few days and see what happens.

Comment: The same thing happened to me.. started visiting SF and SU together in late August (joined before, but didn't post until after the SU beta ended, doh). I got Enthusiast on SU a few days ago and nothing for SF still.

Comment: Follow-up: still waiting for Enthusiast on SF. :(

Comment: @Ether - mine eventually turned up (see my answer) so I suspect there is something more than just viewing the home page required.

Comment: Related issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <strike>current</strike> former accepted answer on this post is wrong, though it was likely true when it was written. See Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485). Basically, it says that logging in is not, by itself, enough to count as a visit.

Answer (score 5):

With Firefox, if you do a save open tabs and exit, it doesn't refresh the pages when you re-open it (so the site doesn't know that you are visiting it). I'm not sure if this is the case with Chrome.

Comment: This could be it (I'm using Firefox at work). I'm active on all the other sites so I will be refreshing the home page and checking out questions etc. so my visit will be recorded. However, if I refresh straight away I don't see a different page so it must have gone to fetch the latest data AND I log off or shut down my PC overnight (both work and home) so there's no way that Firefox could have a cached version of the page ready for me in the morning. I think I see an e-mail coming on

Answer (score 3):

Just show up :) I don't think you have to actually *do* anything, or else it would be stated in the description.

Comment: That's what I thought & I thought I'd been showing up for the same number of days as for SuperUser so when I didn't get the badge I got confused.

Comment: @ChrisF: It's tough to tell, especially since there's no way to track your history on the site from day to day. This has been requested.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as I think some changes went in which made the recording of visits more consistent. If I open any of the sites and check my profile page it always has the "Last activity" as within the last minute.

Comment: My stats say I've been a member for 2 months, visited for **59** days, with **19** consecutive days. At this rate, I'll get the badge just around the year 2038, when Unix bombs and SO vanishes... :)

Comment: This may have been true at one point, but it is not true now. Jeff [has stated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) that there's a difference in the logs between a login and a visit, in response to a user who lost a dozens-of-days-long streak.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is the answer I got from the team:

> if you browse some of the safari 4
>   threads on meta you can get a hint as
>   to what's necessary for the badge.

I've checked some of the other threads and I'm none the wiser. Some people say just opening the page is sufficient, others say you have to refresh the page at least once. The badge hasn't turned up yet so I'm leaning towards me missing a day somehow.

However, since the 15<sup>th</sup>/16<sup>th</sup> of September I have been refreshing the SF page and checking at least one question so if the badge doesn't turn up until the 15<sup>th</sup>/16<sup>th</sup> October I'll know that you need to do at least one refresh.

**EDIT - 30/09/2009**

The badge still hasn't turned up. I must have "missed" a day sometime in early September. So it looks like there is some minimum level of activity required, but what that level is will remain a mystery.

**EDIT - 12/10/2009**

The badge has "finally" turned up. So it seems that I missed a day on the 12th(?) September. It was a Saturday so I would have accessed the sites via Google Chrome at home & if I didn't do a refresh that would support the cached page theory.

Comment: If you check out your own profile and it displays a "Last seen" within the last couple of hours after each hill of the UTC, you're in the clear. Not sure about your particular case though.

Comment: @random - that seems like too much effort. I'm on these sites for about 2 hours a day (max) - an hour at work split between first thing, lunch and last thing before I leave and then another hour at home. As I said in the question, I'm never going to be able to answer enough questions on SF to get lots of rep but the Enthusiast badge would have been nice. If getting it means being more active then I'll have to take my chances.

Comment: Congratulations. Now onto Fanatic!

Answer (score 0):

I have been visiting SO daily from about 2 months, and as far as I remember, I have been always hitting “Refresh” button. I do not have Enthusiast badge. Maybe there is an issue with visiting SO from different IP’s (Monday to Friday work IP and home IP during weekends)?

Comment: You sure you've never missed a single day?

Comment: Quite sure. It was the first thing I started my workday, as well as first thing done in Saturday's morning and Sunday's evening at home (note: using CET my "day" is almost equal to "day" in terms of SO - the shift is only 2 hours).

Comment: I can tell you you didn't hit Meta every day for 2 months, but I can't check on SO.

Comment: I've checked my notes and I think I started on 26th of August. On the begining of October I stopped visiting SU and meta daily, while still visiting SO daily.

Comment: The issue might be when the 'day' is. It's GMT. So for me in Adelaide, Australia, it goes from 10:30am to 10:30am. For someone in the US, it might be 4pm to 4pm. Perhaps if one day you didn't visit until after 4pm, it thought you missed a day. My frustration is that I can't see my streak anywhere, despite writing a query that works it out.

Comment: @Rob Farley - no, 'day' is not an issue for me, since my shift from GMT is onlny one hour. However, Enthusiast badge is still a mystery for me (I finally got it on SO).