# What determines when a user was "seen"?

Tags: support, profile-page

Right now, [my Stack Overflow user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732) says I was "seen" 33 minutes ago. The last entry on the activity list was at 54 minutes ago. I'm pretty sure I didn't vote on any questions or comments in the meantime. Furthermore, I just flagged a comment here on Meta and my Meta user page still says I was seen 10 minutes ago. What actions reset the "seen" counter to zero, and what actions are ignored?

Comment: Look in the corner, to your upper left. Now wave and say "Hi, Jeff!"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated/33310#33310

Comment: I'm wondering what this is too. I still don't see what `seen` is for. Sometimes it says "just now" and then "5 minutes ago" but I haven't done anything for like 2 hours. Does seen mean when I go to my profile, or what?