# What does the 'seen' field value in my profile represent?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines when a user was “seen”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34003/what-determines-when-a-user-was-seen)

This value is changing all the time and I can't figure out what it is exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "seen" field in your profile displays the last time that you were "seen" on or by the site. In other words, it indicates *your last activity* on that particular Stack Exchange site.

It changes all the time because when you're doing things on the site, it's "seeing" you. It's really not all that useful for you, because you know when you've last been active on the site! But it's great for *other* users who are curious when you last logged on.

Comment: Ahhhh, thaaat's what it is, cool thanks.

Comment: @CodyGray - Also, does seen get updated if your client polls the server but you are afk? For example leaving the browser window open.