# Seen date not updated from 2009, though user is in top 23% this week

Tags: support, reputation, timestamps

I thought this is quite funny, looking at [user106011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106011/user106011) profile:
[image]

I've found quite a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/ninjas-are-posting-questions-without-being-seen), with the answer

> *Seen* means the last interval check that was made

But there was only a matter of some minutes difference, while here, it's more than one year!

And the answer to this question: [Account “last activity time” is not always updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated/33310#33310) states that:

> **Seen:** equivalent to LastAccessDate. Activity threshold 30 minutes

So, is this a bug or not? Who can solve the mystery? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course, you don't have to appear to gain rep - questions and answers have a long tail.

Update: Checking the logs, that user genuinely hasn't been seen in a ***long*** time. The screen is correct.

Comment: Thank you, seems he just received some upvotes to an old question. :)

Comment: Hoeray for passive rep!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe one of his old answer got a lot of upvotes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/users/106011/user106011?tab=reputation

Comment: Yes, I just looked at this, and most probably this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

He got 40 reputation this week, at 3/20 and 3/24

https://stackoverflow.com/users/106011/user106011?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think at this possibility..though it's just that question that make me look at his profile.

Comment: It only takes 40 rep to get into the top 23%???? Wow.

Comment: @Spudley, probably, he ranked #3919 for week with that 40 reps http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-03-20/106011#106011

Answer (score 3):

The last [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106011/user106011?tab=activity) for the user was in 2009.  So a last seen date of 2009 seems logical.  It looks like this is one answer that people keep voting for.  Up to 38 votes so far and at least 4 this week.  However, it is strange that people are up-voting it so much since it was posted after an accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, I just observed the same answer, that lead me to his profile.