# Is "seen" working ok? 

Tags: support, profile-page

> [Seen: equivalent to LastAccessDate. Activity threshold 30 minutes. Shown to all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated/33310#33310)

So seen time should updated by every half an hour? I saw [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109309/using-shortcut-keys-in-gmail-through-quicktest-pro) which was asked 9 hours ago & when I went ahead to see [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467529/user1467529) of user who posted the question it shows 8 hours ago.

**UPDATE:**

Now after posting question, I checked & there no such time difference, is it working okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, "seen" refers to all possible user activities, not just asking questions. However for the user in question, the [only activity was the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467529/user1467529?tab=activity), and the slight or discrepancy is explained because of the 30 minutes activity threshold, i.e. any user activity can update "seen" however there is only one update allowed per 30 minutes.

However when the counter passes the 1 hour mark, it only shows hours, so even if it said 8 hours, it could be anywhere from 8 hours exactly to 8 hours 59 minutes. To get the *exact* timestamp on both the question and the profile "seen" field, just hover over them.