# What is LastAccessDate in the Database schema?

Tags: support, data-explorer, schema

I have a doubt regarding the meaning of LastAccessDate in the StackExchange database under the User table. Is it the last date on which the user have performed some activity on the site(like asking questions, commenting etc.) or is it last date when user opened the site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LastAccessDate is the last time they loaded a page on the site, updated at most once every 30 minutes - [equivalent to the "last seen" field on the user's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136843/is-seen-working-ok).