# What does "seen" mean on the profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page

Whenever I open my profile page on Stack Overflow I see a field named **seen**. What does it mean? I saw it read 10 sec ago.

Does it mean someone has viewed my profile? But the profile views are the same as I checked few days back?

Comment: Bottom line: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33310/152859.

Comment: i opened my profile after 2 days, then why does it show "Seen 10 sec ago"?

Comment: Did you read any of the linked posts?? It's pretty clear, I can't explain it any better.

Comment: Presumably it took you 10 seconds to click the link to your profile page after you entered the site.

Comment: @juhana +1 yes that appears logical