# What is 'consecutive' in my profile on stack overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I can't understand what is 'consecutive' in my profile on stack overflow. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full line is something like

> Visited 900 days, 757 consecutive

which simply means a user has visited the site ([and has been active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/is-there-a-minimum-level-of-activity-required-to-get-the-enthusiast-badge)) on 900 days, and currently for 757 [UTC days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) in a row (so without a gap in between).