# Consecutive days problem #97?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I'm pretty depressed that I'm finally one of the people posting this, since I'm usually telling those people "you're obviously wrong", but either I don't understand how consecutive day counting works or this seems impossible:

[image: Screenshot of my user page, with 1 consecutive day and last activity 7 hours ago]

The last activity count is right; I was on SO at about 18:30Z yesterday (Saturday). Is it possible for the consecutive count to be at 1 if my last activity was yesterday? It would seem like it has to be at least 2 then (although I was definitely active Friday; I suspect Saturday is the "missing" day since all I did was poke through the newest question list and check the current flags)

Comment: Related: *[What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199)*

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
2010-10-03 02:09:19 user accessed site
2010-10-02 06:32:30 login
2010-10-01 01:07:43 user accessed site
```

We see a login on 10-2 but no access to internal pages (login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access").

Comment: Oh. Reading through /questions seems like it should qualify as "access", but I guess that's why. Thanks

Comment: @michael why were you logged out in the first place? that's odd

Comment: @Jeff I wasn't on a computer I normally use

Comment: @Jeff Atwood this is good to know, I was bummed to see my SuperUser account go from like nearly 50 something consecutive days to 1 because I was super busy one day and I thought just logging into my page counted as access.

Comment: @Michael I think explained this to you and a few others in chat when explaining how my script works and why it didn't work for many months... Remember, it was the time you were complaining that I am a cheater? :-)

Comment: @The Yeah, I forgot about that. I think you explained it as "you need to access two pages", which seemed wrong and which I actually did in this case; the actual thing you need to do is access a page that's not "homepage style", as Jeff put it

Comment: Wait, so just scanning the initial page of questions, does *not* count as 'access'? Odd, I thought I saw another answer that said any activity - guess it's not active enough. :) (And explains why I've not gotten the badge, either).

Comment: @John I've read quite a few of the consecutive days posts; I think this is the first I've heard of this particular restriction, so I'm glad it's finally documented. Jonathan says "Just show up" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21900), Timothy says "The only minimum activity required is being logged in and coming to the site" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24887), and Robert (apparently wrongly) says "Over at Server Fault, there were many, many days I did nothing *but* visit their homepage and I got my Fanatic badge" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29304)

Comment: @Michael, yes, this explains why my script had to access two pages, one was the homepage!

Comment: Wait, so "access" represents more, um, activity than "activity"? From all the dupe questions on here about consecutive days, the rules probably need to be made more clear.  Currently, the consecutive day implementation is kinda like a [door handle with a "Push" sign](http://chriselyea.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/PushPullDoors.jpg) on it. Nothing wrong with folks striving for the badge, especially if it encourages folks to be active.  I mean, to be access-ible-ling-ige-ish-er.

Comment: **So description of this badge should be changed from 'visit' to 'read posts'**