# Consecutive days calculation

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I read somewhere the consecutive days calculation is triggered each time a login authentication is done. My consecutive days seem to be disappearing, too, and I wondered why, until the following solution came to my mind:

If I don't restart my browser for a few days (which is very common due to Notebook hibernation), and my Session at stackoverflow remains open, does StackOverflow count the days between?

Additional question: If I just browse the site, does this count as consecutive usage? Or do I have to do any actions, like voting and answering?

Comment: See any of the many questions on the right ->

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consecutive days problem #97?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Were you thinking of the information presented in Jeff's answer to [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

There are two levels of being seen: just logging in and actually accessing the site. If your computer is in hibernation, you aren't using it, so there's no activity going on that counts towards the consecutive days count. Merely logging in won't count as activity as far as the consecutive days count is concerned, either. Accessing a "non-landing" page should be enough to count as activity, though voting or leaving a comment certainly wouldn't hurt.