# Doesn't Logging in From Mobile Count as Logging In

Tags: support, activity-badges

I was actually trying to earn the Fanatic achievement, therefore on some rare days, whenever I am unable to connect from my PC, I connect from my mobile device, (Nokia 2700, Opera 6.0).

Now in the past, whenever I had to do this, later on in the day I got an scope to log in using my PC anyway, so there wasn't any chance of breaking consecutive log in.

Now several thing could have happened here, one is caching on my mobile device and the second is caching by Opera(they actually optimize every page request through their server and of course, caching could be involved). I actually opened the home page and then didn't do any activity. I verified that I am logged in using my account.

And to more confusion to all that, few days back I swapped open Id to my Facebook account, but my mobile device still had to old logged in session(using my Google account).

So, what actually did happen. I hope stackexchange would look into the issue of properly setting the number of consecutive days if they are able to find logs of my activity involving all the different accounts.

Comment: What different accounts? You don't mention any other accounts in your text, only that you changed the OpenId (which, by the way, doesn't matter at all).

Comment: The two accounts are now connected, I guess there was a delay in having them connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the home page. [It doesn't count as activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485).

And you probably aren't going to have much luck getting it restored. As you can imagine, manual database changes based on digging through activity logs is not high on the priority list. Especially when it sets a precedent. There are many of these posts on Meta already.

Comment: Thanks. But in my brain, the message of cartoons, "now he tells us.." is going on :P. Oh well, I guess I have to restart. Too bad cause I was pretty close to that badge.

Comment: @Gunner I feel your pain. I have done the same too many times.

Comment: @Gunner @Renesis re "the easiest way to get the visit counted" - IMO, the *easiest* way to ensure it is counted **is to do something**, for example, answer a question. Otherwise, it reeks of *gaming*... just sayin'...

Comment: @Marc Fair enough, I've removed that from the post.

Comment: @Marc @Renesis: I was wondering about "Fanatics" who go on tour or need get out of everyday life. If you are a human(fanatic or not), you would want to do that at some point. This may make it difficult to connect to the internet, say you are on long flights or going mountain hiking. Perhaps, they ought to relax the condition for this badge and modifying the requirements.