# Consecutive Days

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

My consecutive days count is constantly resetting.  I was on SO last night multiple times and today I log in and it says it didn't see me last night.  I've had a suspicion that this has been happening to me in the past, but I was never 100% for sure.  Sometimes I thought maybe it was a 24hr period and not a full day?  But I know I was on my mac last night working and checked Stack Overflow multiple times and this morning I'm on my PC and it says today is 1 day consecutive.  And looking at the calendar it confirms it shows no activity for me last night.

Comment: What did you do on the site though? I'm pretty sure a certain amount of activity each visit needs to be registered to count as active

Comment: Were you logged in using the same user account? The symptoms indicate the otherwise.

Comment: The answer is the same as in the other post. All you did yesterday was visit the homepage five times. That doesn't count for the consecutive days number.

Comment: The Stack Overflow "day" starts at 00:00 UTC. That's something like 6 or 7PM in Illinois. If you only logged in last night, you were, in fact, logging in today.

Comment: I was definitely logged in as the same user.  I just viewed a few answers and read a comment on one of my questions.