# consecutive days count is wrong for sure

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Please have a look at this [image: pic]

I am 100% sure that there were no consecutive 24 hours, that I have not visited my stackoverflow. But, the consecutive days count just skipped a day. My last two logins are around:

21st March 11.30 PM PDT

22nd March 10.00 PM PDT

How can it possibly happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Our web logs show that you did access Stack Overflow on March 22 three times, but all three hits were to the home page.

Unfortunately, the [home page doesn't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485), as we require some minimum activity elsewhere on the site to qualify for "site access", such as a [Question/Show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182942/pause-for-certain-time-in-sencha/9183722#9183722) page or a [Question/List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) page.

I'll grant you that missed day, though, *just this once*, so you'd better be more active in the future :)

Comment: Ahhh, that's why mine count. My browser lands on `/questions` by default. So even if I don't actually look at anything, it still counts.

Comment: Just visiting your user profile page also does the job.

Comment: I just read questions and try to answer them if possible. That seems to have been working quite well so far.