# Understanding how I missed a day for consecutive SO visit counts

Tags: support, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

Okay, I'm trying not to make this an "I wuz cheated" post :) about consecutive day counts on SO, so I'll just try to respectfully ask how my visit count was reset. I've read through some other posts on this issue, and I can't quite seem to find one that says "aha, this is the reason :)"

The pop-up calendar on my profile shows I had no visit Sunday, 9 Sep 12, but I did visit, checked my profile, and looked at the current question list on my phone approximately mid-day yesterday (guestimating around noon CDT 9-9-12) which should be well within the 9-9 date in GMT). Heck, even made sure to check the list during a football game Saturday :)

I've been diligently maintaining the daily visits, and only had it up to 55, but the reset was still a little disheartening. If I can learn how I messed up, I'll try to avoid the mistake in the future.

Comment: Just visiting the home page is not enough to count. You need to do something more for it to be counted.

Comment: Understand, but I didn't "just" visit the home page. As I noted in the post, I checked my personal profile *and* the current question list.

Comment: On the bright side, you'll be able to get a proper gold badge before you get your "I signed my name correctly" badge :-)

Comment: I think when you check the profile, you should also check the pop-up calendar, to see whether you are marked as visited for that day.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Okay, I guess I have to plead stupid on that comment. I take it that's something else I did wrong?

Comment: @nhahtdh I did - and it showed my "55 Consecutive" days, *and* it also indicated "Last seen 8 seconds ago..."

Comment: @DavidW: No no, not at all, but wouldn't it be much awesomer if your first gold badge were one for genuine merit, rather than one of the few "just show up and you get one" badges? I mean, eventually you'll get the Fanatic one anyway, but it isn't really one that's worth aspiring to in its own right, is it? I always see it as a bit of a consolation badge...

Comment: @KerreskSB Oh, of course, but having eight weeks of visits get blown up still draws out a bit of an "aw, shucks, *really*?" reaction. There are so many topics on SO here, its humbling to realize how much I *don't* know, and hand-in-hand with that is the fact that it does take some diligence to find good questions to which I feel I can make a positive, constructive contribution :)

Comment: @DavidW: I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say. I was suggesting that when you check out SO profile (and question list) for the badge, you can also check whether the date on the calendar is marked in green for that day. I guess you might have missed because you checked SO a bit later or a bit earlier than the time SO goes over to a new day.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the input. My understanding is that the "day" starts at what translates to be 7PM CDT, so a mid-day check should be well within that window.

Answer (score 9):

The consecutive days badges are easy, but not free. So if you want to guarantee to get them within 100 days, you need to counter the two pitfalls:

1. Timezone.  As long as you have two visits in a day around the same time (for example in the morning and in the afternoon). You counter this.
2. Does the visit count. Visiting the home page does not count, so be sure you have at least a single action (like a vote or a comment). Added advantage is that they can be proven so if there is really a bug you can prove that you have been there.

But of course it is better to have a significant contribution three times a week, than to visit for the badge each day.

A last piece of advice, try to have fun. Because time flies when you are having fun.

Comment: +1 for the second last sentence! I already thought about suggesting a change to these badges from visiting to "did something useful".

Comment: For more details on Gamecat's point #2, see [Consecutive days problem #97](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482).