# Is there any bug with the visited day checking system at Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

Just asking if any one has seen this error before?

For me, during weekday I use my work machine to log in to Stack Overflow and during the weekend, I use my own laptop to log in.

I'm pretty sure that I did log in to Stack Overflow over the last weekend but when I go to work today and log in to SO with my work machine, it shows a record that I didn't log in to SO on the last Saturday and Sunday!

I have no problem with that, just want to report the system's error if it really exists!

Answer (score 2):

Days are counted using UTC (GMT). This may cause strange behaviors when you are living somewhere other than Europe.

Specifically, you may "run over" a day without noticing, because the beginning of a Stack Exchange day is not aligned with the beginning of a day in your country.

Comment: In fact days are counted using UTC which is somewhere in Europe! Your second sentence is, however, correct.