# Activity on StackExchange Site on a particular Date

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, consecutive-days

I just noticed my Consecutive day counter of Meta was reset on 26th of March 2013, but I am sure I have visited the site, but I still want to confirm.

So is there a way that I get to know about my activity on SO site for a particular day?

Comment: You need to do more than just visit to trigger activity - voting, commenting etc count but just looking at a page may not trigger an official 'visit' log.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your activities on Stack Overflow from [your activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821057/zaheer-ahmed?tab=activity&sort=all). (We have to navigate to particular date). Also you can visit [your votes tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821057/zaheer-ahmed?tab=votes&sort=all)

<strike>But talking about the consecutive day counter, we just need to visit a website. (If we don't do any activity it still count towards our consecutive day)</strike>

* <sup>Link for OP only. You can see the votes tab on your own profile.</sup>

Comment: Not all visits count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Didn't get you. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You say "we just need to visit a website". That is not true. I'll dig up the post Jeff Atwood made about this, but not all visits count.

Comment: See [Consecutive days problem #97?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Still confusing (sometimes I just visit my profile and it still counts)