# What counts as activity on SE sites for consecutive visits?

Tags: discussion, support, consecutive-days, activity-badges

As per Jeff's [reply here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/212576):

> **login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access"**

So, what exactly are the pages/actions that can count my visit as "**access**"? Can I just go visit any question and cast and upvote/downvote on it to have the day counted? Is the same applicable for comment votes?

As far as I understand, any activity which gets logged in the activity tab ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/212576/hjpotter92?tab=activity) for me) is counted as a successful visit.

If that is so, I'd be more than glad to upvote one or two posts everyday. If not, can someone please provide a detailed/short list(probably as *community wiki*) of accepted measures which may lead to fanatic badges?

**P.S.**: I know any kind of posting is always counted for this; be it a question, reply or a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I log in and go to my profile page, the number of consecutive visits increments before I do anything, so I think just doing that is sufficient and self-confirmatory.

Comment: Good point. Of course, that requires remembering what the count was the day before. ;)

Comment: Did you try it for two days-in-a-row?

Comment: I think it works two days in a row... try it by logging in to a different stackexchange site if you want to test cleanly without curtailing your normal SO use.