# Consecutive days counter resets for no reason

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I have on purpose been visiting every day on SO, including weekends for a few weeks now. I read and comment on questions, answering them when I can, but I am on in the morning and at night every day, and sometimes into the wee hours of the morning. I know I have not missed a day and yet the counter still resets. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can click the counter to see on which days the system thinks you were absent.

Comment: Stack Exchange uses UTC, are you _sure_ you have visited and done something on every UTC day?

Comment: This totally got me when three quarters of the way to a full years' attendance. Ultimately, live with it. SE's date management is weird from a user perspective.

Comment: @GrantThomas Just move to central Europe if it bothers you that much ;)

Comment: @Servy I assure you it doesn't, and the fact that it shouldn't bother anyone was what I was trying to convey. It's weird, but so what? It can be one of those things, giving an "oh dear!" moment, but, all the same.

Comment: @GrantThomas So you think that everyone lives in whatever timezone you live in, and that the entire site should revolve around that?  That would fix the issues for you, but then create issues for everyone else.  The fundamental problem is that people use this site from all over the world every single day, and you have to pick some timezone to be the one the site uses.  No matter what you pick lots of people will have a problem with it.

Comment: @Servy What are you on about? Are my comments being universally translated into their exact opposite in meaning, or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses UTC time to determine when *days* pass. You seem to "miss a day" a lot over weekends (at least in Stack Exchange Time). So I would speculate that you are changing your routine of visiting the site over the weekend.

If you visit the site early on a Saturday (for example), and then not again until late in the day on Sunday, it is easy to "miss a day" (a 24-hour window) in Stack Exchange time.

Comment: The other day I was logged in, had activity on questions, not just homepage, and even signed in with more than one machine/browser, and yet, no credit for that day. I give up. It is just not right. Who knows. I guess I will just go about my day and forget about the badge for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange uses UTC TimeZone. To make sure you have the right time, look at the dropdown menu of your profil.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jeff's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485), a visit requires more than just visiting the login and "home page style pages" (which are not defined).

For your visit to count toward your consecutive days, you will need to dig more deeply into the site. Details are scarce, but I assume that these would not be considered "home page style pages":

- The review queues
- The question/answer edit pages

Comment: If interacting with questions and commenting doesn't count as activity, then WTF? Makes no sense.

Comment: It seems logical that answering a question should be counted as activity, but the guidelines are unclear on that point.

Comment: Viewing an individual question is pretty well-established as being sufficient

Comment: AFAIK visiting your profile is enough to count as active day