# Are consecutive days counted each 24 hours or by UTC?

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days

I'm pretty sure I've visited Stack Overflow *and* Meta Stack Overflow every day before 4 PM PDT (midnight UTC) for the past 50 days. I can recall seeing it say (I believe) 35(?) consecutive days visited a few weeks back. Then, all of a sudden, the counter reset *on both* sites. That got me wondering:

Say you visit at 6:30 UTC, would not visiting until 6:35 UTC the next day reset the counter, or do you just need to visit once every UTC day?

Comment: UTC. And an actual action is required.

Comment: @Bart could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Bart if you could define "action" also...

Comment: This answers the UTC question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start and this the action part: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to visit every UTC day. And on this visit you have to access the page. Just logging in, is not enough. You have to visit pages not part of the "homepage style". So just scanning the new questions doesn't count as an action.