# Sorting of accounts in profile summary

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, sorting

Almost every section in the profile summary page can be sorted.

- We can sort the questions and answers by age, activity, or votes
- We can sort badges by class, name, or age
- We can sort bounties by active, earned, and awarded

But there is no sort option for the accounts.  It is always sorted by reputation.

> [image]

With so many sites now, it seems like SE only wants me to pay attention to the 5 sites I have the most reputation, rather than giving me the option to sort by activity, reputation, and maybe another criterion (age?).

I have 15 accounts currently, and while I am only really active (from an asking/answering standpoint on MSO and SO), I'm trying to explore some of the other sites and have asked a recent question on Seasoned Advice.  It would be nice if I could sort this list by recent activity so I can see rep changes or other changes in activity at a quick glance without having to click "view more" and then find the site I want to see.

Obviously when it is just 1 new site I asked a new question on, it is easy enough to keep tabs on the posts, but if I decide to ask or answer questions on 2 or 3 new sites, it would be nice to be able to see which of my sites has the most recent activity from my profile.

The definition of "activity" is going to be subject to some debate and probably in be based on what is easiest to capture quickly via caching but in my opinion the best actions that would bump an account would be based on stuff that happens without your own actions:

- Having a question answered
- Any rep change
- Having a post edited
- A comment on any part of your post (not just stuff that would get you pinged on)
- Updates to a Favorited post
- Earning a badge
- Getting pinged via comment
- Follow up comments on posts you commented on (this one could get annoying but would be helpful in cases where someone forgot to use an @-comment)

Obviously if it is based on actions that you perform yourself, it is somewhat pointless as you know what sites you were performing actions on, but including "Asking a Question" or "Answering a Question" in this list would make sense since those are the primary actions of the site.

I would not include actions like performing reviews, making edits, voting on posts in the actions.

For sites outside of SO/MSO, Meta activity using similar criteria should also bump an account.

Comment: You can always click "view more"

Comment: Yes I can (which I did mention), but the summary page is often a nice way to get a quick update on everything, so it would be nice to be able to sort it by another criterion rather than just always reputation.

Comment: How is activity sorting supposed to function? Just, whatever site your last action was on? If so, what purpose does it serve? If not, how do you plan to measure "activity"? (@ColeJohnson)

Comment: @Emrakul I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: @Emrakul my opinion it should be based on activity that happens without your direct involvement.  The purpose being to make sure some action that might warrant your attention doesn't get missed.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah. If someone answers or comments on your posts, it generates a notification. What additional information are you looking for that the current notification system does not provide?

Comment: @Emrakul I almost didn't included getting an answer in the list because of the notification, but the logic of including it is that once you read the notification, it goes away.  The activity "level" will still reflect this.  For comments, my thoughts would expand beyond cases where you normally be notified as you are only notified of comments on your own posts, not answers of questions you asked (or questions of posts you answered).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

---

Can we please implement this? Maybe have "tabs" like everything else on the overview page. Maybe `[rep] [activity]`? We could then default to `[rep]` so it isn't a sudden change? We could then save the last viewed "tab" as a preference like the other "tabs" there.

---

I would define activity as the ranking of the amount of actions on a site during a day. For example, if I perform 8 actions on MSO, 5 on SO, and 9 on SU, all in the same UTC day, sort it SU, MSO, SO.

The next day, I would perform an action on MSO first, MSO would be bumped to the top. I then perform 2 actions on SO, bump SO to the top. Essentially keep how it was the previous day, but bump sites based on action count for the day.

Comment: So actions reset at the day's end. Doesn't that make the sorting method useless for a significant amount of time each day? Additionally, I'd like to request a definition of 'action,' since there are dozens of actions one can take on a site.

Comment: @Emrakul [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97) defines action.

Comment: So, it's the number of times you've accessed anything on the site?

Comment: @Emrakul no. It's the number of times you've done something _with_ the site. Like flagging is one action. Voting is one. Editing is one.