# How do I re-order the communities on my profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page

On my profile page, under the communities tab, the top 5 sites where I have the most reputation are shown:

[image: my communities tab]

I'd like to remove English Language & Usage from this list (since I'm not very active there), and instead, I'd like to replace it Game Development.

How do I do this? The "edit list" link only brings me to the "Hide Communities" tab. I don't want to hide the community from everybody, I just don't want it showing up in the top 5 sites.

@RobertLongson suggested getting more rep in another site, or offering a bounty in EL&U, but I'm looking for a way to re-order the communities regardless of rep (since I have 3-4 communities with more rep than Game Dev).

(Related: [How to remove a specific post from "Top Network Posts"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/how-to-remove-a-specific-post-from-top-network-posts?rq=1), which deals with Top Network Posts)

Comment: If you hide it (within the Hide Communities tab), it will be removed from the list. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @RobertLongson No, because I don't want to hide it from everybody, I only want it not to be in the top 5 communities.

Comment: Get more rep in something else then so it drops off the list. Or offer a bounty on something in EL&U.

Comment: @RobertLongson (I've added more details to the post.) Is there a way to re-order them without changing rep, like you can in the "Your Communities" section of the Stack Exchange dropdown on the top of the page? The community I'm trying to add (Game Dev) has ~20 less rep than EL&U.

Comment: It wouldn't be the top 5 then would it?

Comment: This is not possible. Think a feature request already exists asking to let us decide what sites will be listed there, will search. Here is the request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190768/sorting-of-accounts-in-profile-summary.

Answer (score 3):

In short: you can't. Such feature does not exist.

I tend to agree with this behavior. This list is not your personal list of communities, but the public view of all communities where you have an account. Anyone visiting your profile will see this list.

Just in case you missed it, there is a customizable list in the top bar, where you can choose the exact position of each site:

> [image]

Personally, I do support [Sorting of accounts in profile summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190768/sorting-of-accounts-in-profile-summary) feature request, and would also support a request to add a "Featured Community" section to the profile page, where the user can choose one site that will appear there, with all his/her stats of course.

Comment: That feature-request seems close enough to what I want, so I'll make sure to upvote it. Thanks! As for the "Featured Community" suggestion, I also think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Cheers, feel free to start a feature request for featured community, don't think it exists yet.

Comment: [Done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267205/287999) Thanks!