# Add a "Featured Community" section on the profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

(Original idea from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267203/287999))

Every user has one community that they're really active in, and (usually) have a lot of good questions/answers there as well. I suggest that user profiles have a "Featured Community" section, where a user's stats for a particular community of their choice be displayed.

The "Featured Community" area would be a small box showing the user's badge count and rep, with a link that takes you to their profile page for that website.

It would be placed right above the communities tab:

[image: arrow pointing to where it would be inserted]

and "Communities" would be renamed "Other Communities" if it was enabled. (If the featured community is in the Communities tab already, the Communities tab skips over that site.) This would allow users to show the site they are most active in more prominently (even if it's not their highest-rep site.)

It would be disabled by default, and if a user hasn't picked one (because they are either new or haven't found the feature yet), on the Profile section of the user's page, it would say "Featured Community: You haven't chosen a featured community yet. Click here to set one." (This would be visible only to the user.)

The Featured Community could be changed or disabled at any time in Settings.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I don't think it's a particularly useful idea. Cheifly because; I don't care what a users top-rated posts are on SalesForce.stackexchange.com if I'm looking at their GraphicDesign.stackexchangecom profile page. It's irrelevant information to me at that time. And the web is full of irrelevant information. I could do without extra noise, thank-you-very-much.

It is useful to see if they are *a member of* salesforce.stackexhange, yes. But what relevance does it have to me to know they've asked / solved some problems in something I have no knowledge or interest in?

Comment: Might be true, but other personal stats might not be of interest to everyone, e.g. website, About Me and more. Still, user can fill those.

Answer (score 5):

There is already the accounts/communities section, where the accounts are listed in order of reputation. You may change the order if you are inactive in some account by simply hiding the inactive account.

You can already see the rep and badges there. The top posts on the sites are already seen in the Top Network posts section. So I think it would just display information that is already on your user page.

For clarification, here is a screenshot form my profile page. I think it is clear that my top account is Mathematics. The badges can be seen by hovering over the reputation.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Rather than trying to argue "We don't need this feature" (debatable) you're pointing out that "This feature already exists! Use it if you like". In particular, hiding all but one community via the "Edit list" link, you can make any of your communities your "featured community", if you like.