# After receiving my Enthusiast badge the counter restarted to 0

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

After receiving my *[Enthusiast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67402#67402)* badge the counter restarted to 0. Why do I have to wait another 100 consecutive days to receive my frantic badge?

Comment: It's spelled "[Fanatic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic)", but I like [your version](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frantic#Adjective). :)

Comment: This got nothing with you getting the badge, you just missed a day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you [received the Enthusiast badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast?userid=5574607) on Stack Overflow on Tuesday, February 9.  Currently (just after midnight UTC on Sunday, February 14) the Fanatic badge tracker on [your profile on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5574607/xy-bane?tab=topactivity) says that you've visited SO on three consecutive days.

Thus, it looks like you may have missed a day just after getting the Enthusiast badge.

You can easily check if that's the case by going to [the "profile" tab on your, um, profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5574607/xy-bane?tab=profile) and clicking the "visited *x* days, *y* consecutive" row on the right-hand side.  This will bring up a calendar pop-up that shows you on which days Stack Overflow thinks you've visited it.  For example, here's what mine looks like:

> [image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow profile calendar popup showing days on which I have visited the site]

The days highlighted in green are the ones on which SO thinks I've visited the site.  You can see that I've missed Thursday, so I currently have three consecutive visited days just like you.  (Actually I'm not sure if the Fanatic badge progress counter counts the current day or not, so you might've missed Wednesday instead.  Either way, I suspect you have indeed missed a day recently.)

Note that SE [defines a "day" as starting and ending at midnight UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).  If you're living in a time zone far from UTC (like, say, in the U.S., or in eastern Asia), this may happen in the middle of your local day, so that e.g. visits in the morning can fall on a different UTC day than visits in the evening.  If you're not aware of this, and sometimes check SO a bit earlier or later than usual, it's easy to accidentally miss a day.

Also note that [just logging in or visiting the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97) does *not* count as "visiting" SO for the purposes of the badge.  You'll have to actually load at least one "internal" page (I'm pretty sure question pages count; I suspect that so do e.g. search, review and user profile pages) for your visit to get properly counted.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know about that calendar!